# terminating a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I a have a C program which calls to threads.

```
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, readdata, NULL);
iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, timer_func, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

Thread 2 returns after performing some function, after which I want to stop the execution of thread 1. How should I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can stop the thread using `pthread_cancel`:

```
pthread_cancel(thread1);
```

And in `readdata`:

```
/* call this when you are not ready to cancel the thread */
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
...
/* call this when you are ready to cancel the thread */
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
```

See the [pthread_cancel man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) for more information - there's an example included.

If you don't want to use pthread_cancel, you can use a global flag that is set by the main thread and read by thread 1. Also, you can use any of the IPC methods, like establishing a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) between the threads.

Answer (score 2):

You should signal to the thread that you wish it to stop work, and then wait for it to do so.  For example, you could set a boolean flag that the thread tests regularly. If that flag indicates that work has been cancelled, then the thread should return from the thread function.

Don't attempt to forcibly terminate the thread from the outside because this will leave synchronisation objects in indeterminate state, lead to deadlocks etc.

Comment: not possible, the thread will be stuck in reading from a socket, when there is nothin to read, so I want to terminate it from the outside

Comment: An interrupting (non-`SA_RESTART`) signal handler can cause a `read` to return with `EINTR`, which would allow you to get back control and have the thread exit itself.

Answer (score 2):

Thread1 must have a flag which it verifies from time to time to see if it should abort itself.

There are ways to abort a thread from outside, but this is very dangerous. Don't.

Something like:

```
thread1stop=TRUE; //Thread 1 has access to this boolean value
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

tkill(tid, SIGTERM) is the call you are looking for I do believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop thread1 by calling `pthread_cancel(thread1)`.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_cancel() function sends a cancellation request to the thread.

After sending the request to cancel the thread you should check the return code to confirm that the thread was actually cancelled or not.

Here is a simple example:

```
rc = pthread_cancel(iret2);
if(rc) printf("failed to cancel the thread\n");
```

For further reference:

http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-39.htm

Other sources which might be useful to you.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html